# Right way to extract multiple values from string using regex in ruby 1.8

Tags: ruby, regex, string, ruby-1.8

I'm relatively new to ruby and I'm trying to figure out the "ruby" way of extracting multiple values from a string, based on grouping in regexes. I'm using ruby 1.8 (so I don't think I have named captures).

I could just match and then assign $1,$2 - but I feel like there's got to be a more elegant way (this is ruby, after all).

I've also got something working with grep, but it seems hackish since I'm using an array and just grabbing the first element:

```
input="FOO: 1 BAR: 2"
foo, bar = input.grep(/FOO: (\d+) BAR: (\d+)/){[$1,$2]}[0]
p foo
p bar
```

I've tried searching online and browsing the [ruby docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Enumerable.html), but haven't been able to figure anything better out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rubys [String#match](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-match) method returns a [MatchData](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/MatchData.html) object with the method [captures](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/MatchData.html#method-i-captures) to return an Array of captures.

```
>> string = "FOO: 1 BAR: 2"
=> "FOO: 1 BAR: 2"
>> string.match /FOO: (\d+) BAR: (\d+)/
=> #<MatchData "FOO: 1 BAR: 2" 1:"1" 2:"2">
>> _.captures
=> ["1", "2"]
>> foo, bar = _
=> ["1", "2"]
>> foo
=> "1"
>> bar
=> "2"
```

To Summarize:

```
foo, bar = input.match(/FOO: (\d+) BAR: (\d+)/).captures
```

Comment: So something like `foo, bar = input.match(/FOO: (\d+) BAR: (\d+)/).captures`? Definitely more readable

Comment: Nice timing, I literally just altered my original post with the same thing. Yep, that'll do it.

Answer (score 1):

Either:

```
foo, bar = string.scan(/[A-Z]+: (\d+)/).flatten
```

or:

```
foo, bar = string.match(/FOO: (\d+) BAR: (\d+)/).captures
```

Answer (score 1):

Use scan instead:

```
input="FOO: 1 BAR: 2"

input.scan(/FOO: (\d+) BAR: (\d+)/) #=> [["1", "2"]]
```